# I need a JavaScript runtime environment

Tags: javascript

I'm reading books on JavaScript programming, and I need an environment like Python's [IDLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE_%28Python%29) to type JavaScript commands into and then see the results like you would in IDLE.

Is there an environment where you can do such a thing?

Answer (score 14):

Any of the major browsers (IE, FireFox, Chrome, Safari, etc..) will execute and display the results of JavaScript code that you put into it.

You can open the developer console in Chrome and in IE using <kbd>F12</kbd> and in Firefox using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>. Alternatively you can simply put it into a `.html` file.

Comment: This answer really needs to say more about *how* to put the Javascript into your browser; in particular, it ought to mention the Javascript console.

Answer (score 13):

I find http://jsfiddle.net/ to be a good test environment for trying things out (in JavaScript, HTML and CSS), if you just want to try something easily and now using your browser.

Comment: I second jsfiddle, especially because it's really plug&play. You don't need to worry about connecting your HTML and CSS to your javascript properly, and it reacts almost instantly. You just write your code, write your HTML, press a button and you see the result instantly. And because it's a website, you can link other people to your code extremely easily for debugging and demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Mainstream browsers’ dev tools have a console for executing expressions:

- [Evaluating Expressions in Google Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console#evaluating-expressions).
- The [Internet Explorer F12 tools console](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589530(v=vs.85).aspx).
- The [Firefox Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Web_Console).

See also [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue). It is similar to the already mentioned jsFiddle.

Comment: @MattThrower See first comment of the first answer. That answer was edited since then. My answer points to exactly what is needed and there is not much point copy-pasting the information that is already perfectly worded. Please apply a bit of common sense next time instead of following the guidelines blindly.

Comment: Reminders to use common sense are always appreciated. But in this case, I already did. Mileage varies.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the answers centre on JavaScript code in the web browser. If you're interested in server-side JavaScript code (or more generally, JavaScript code in non-browser environments), then you've got a couple of other options:

- [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) is currently the most popular server-side JavaScript framework and comes with an interactive console. Once you've installed Node.js, you can start the console either from the Start Menu, or by typing `node` into a terminal.
- There's also a reasonable amount of buzz about [Nashorn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_%28JavaScript_engine%29), which is bundled with Java 8. Once you've installed JDK 8, you can start the console by running `jjs`, which depending on your OS will either be available automatically from the terminal, or found at `$JAVA_HOME/bin/jjs`.

Answer (score 0):

As for actual IDE's, you could use Visual Studio (express version is free). They've added better JS intellisense support in the past few releases.

Answer (score 0):

Jetbrains Webstorm is an IDE you can use as well, if that's the sort of thing you're looking into.

Otherwise, there's probably an eclipse plugin.

There's also Sublime Text and Atom, that, with a few plugins, can do it very well.